# Shortest route GA: One loop through one dataset vs multiple loops through subsets of the same data?

Tags: genetic-algorithms, evolutionary-algorithms, genetic-programming

I've a rather simple question for a school project. We're developing a GA solution for the following problem:

Chromosome: A location with lat-lon coords. There are two types of locations - up to 15 waypoints from user input, and a dataset of about 3-400 stations.

Gene: A route consisting of all waypoints (incl. a fixed start and end) + 1 station.

Fitness function: Shortest path.

Stop condition: Run duration - configurable, default 3 seconds.

We're discussing two possible implementations:

- A problem set of all waypoints and **all** stations, kinda like soccer team assignment or nurse rostering design. Run GA **once** on all of that.
- A problem set of all waypoints and **one** station, do TSP. Run GA for **number-of-stations-in-dataset** iterations.

Which is better, in terms of design, efficiency, and performance?